# Dropdown sign in menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using jQuery to animate a dropdown sign in div. The sign up form uses PHP to check if the user exists in the database. However, if I echo something the dropdown menu goes away and you have to click it again to see the error message. Here's how the login looks:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Sign in">
</form>

<?php
    session_start();

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    include("connect.php");

    if($username && $password){
        $password = md5($password);
        $getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password = '$password'");
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($getquery);
            if($numrows != 0){
                setcookie('username', $username, time()+3600);
            } else {
                echo "Invalid username.";
            }
    }
?>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3rr9w/1/

As you see, when you press the submit button the dropdown menu goes up again.

Comment: Try to isolate your problem in http://www.jsfiddle.net/ and maybe it will be easier to help you. Anyway, where's your jquery animation code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3rr9w/2/ check this

Comment: Did you think about making an ajax call to the server to avoid the postback?

Comment: @AdamTal As as PHP/JS noob, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the comment, I would suggest you using an ajax call (just search google for jquery ajax call to php).

For answering your current problem without making things more complicated, add this to the end of your code:

```
<script>
<?php
    if ($_POST['username']) {
        echo 'var postBack = true;';
    } else {
        echo 'var postBack = false;'
    }
?>
if (postBack) {
    $("#signin").show();
}
</script>
```

- You can make the signin visible by default and hide it if postBack is false.

Comment: Thanks for the help, would this work with 2 divs? For example with a $POST_['regusername']?

Comment: Yes, you can duplicate this code, but change the postBack variable name (so you won't define it twice) and the $("#signin").show(); to something like $("#register").show();